# how to parse values (iterate) from an api, within a list of dictionaries python

Tags: python-3.x, api, loops, dictionary, parsing

I am trying to parse info (from "result") from an HTTP API which is in a list of dictionaries. How can I iterate to parse only the following values from all dictionaries?

"a_name":
"ch":
"e":

```
[
  {
    "2H": {
      "time": 156450, 
      "n_ap": 10, 
      "n_rad": 9, 
      "xyz": {
        "is_c": false, 
        "is_d": false, 
        "num_a": 0, 
        "num_d": 0
      }, 
      "o_time": 276, 
      "q_t": 16, 
      "result": [
        {
      "a_name": "abc", 
          "ch": 2, 
          "e": 12,  
          "s_f_list": {
            "b_l": [
              "C20"
            ], 
            "ch_l": {
              "CW160": [], 
              "CW20": [
                1, 
                6, 
                11
              ], 
              "CW4": [], 
              "CW8": []
            }
          }, 
          "s_id": "2z"
        }, 
        {
          "a_name": "abcd", 
          "ch": 3, 
          "e": 13, 
          "s_f_list": {
            "b_l": [
              "C20"
            ], 
            "ch_l": {
              "CW160": [], 
              "CW20": [
                1, 
                6, 
                11
              ], 
              "CW40": [], 
              "CW80": []
            }
          }, 
          "s_id": "2z"
        }, 

        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
```

I have tried the following code but I'm able to parse only first value.
I'm new to python so if anyone here could help with this I would be very thankful.

```
import requests
url = "https://....."
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()
a_name = data[0]["2H"]["result"][0]["a_name"]
ch =data[0]["2H"]["result"][0]["ch"]
print(a_name)
print(ch)
```

output I received is : 
    abc
    2

Expected output:

```
a_name= abc ,ch = 2,e = 12
a_name= abcd ,ch = 3,e = 13
a_name= abcde ,ch = 4,e = 14
.  
.
```

I'm new to python so if anyone here could help with this I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a generator and a list comprehension that contains a nested dictionary comprehension. Not tested btw.

```
def gen_get_items(d, keys_list):
    for s in keys_list:
        if s in d.keys():
            yield s, d[s]

result_keys = ["aname", "ch", "e"]
results = data[0]["2H"]["result"]
specific_results = [
                     {k: v for k, v in gen_get_items(r, result_keys)} 
                       for r in results
                    ]

for specific_result in specific_results:
    print(specific_result)
```

Comment: Glad to hear it! Do try to remember to mark answers as accepted if they fulfil your question (I see you’re a newish user so thought I’d give you a heads up about this).